# Server times out when using HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, https

I'm running a remote react server with a  NGINX load balancer.
When I use HTTP, I have no issues. But when I set HTTPS=True in my react environment, I get bad gateway when I try connecting the webpage.

The NGINX log says the following:

`2021/07/06 10:01:07 [error] 10365#0: *62 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 155.4.218.180, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.50.3.152:80/favicon.ico", host: "remdent.com", referrer: "http://remdent.com/"`

And 3 more similar messages claiming upstream was prematurely closed.
How do I remedy this?

Comment: I think that error from Nginx is indicating that the connection was closed by your upstream server. How is it configured? Do you know the timeout value?

Comment: I feel you might be on to something. Let me check.

Comment: Where do i find the Node.js settings btw?

Comment: `req.connection.setTimeout(100000); //100 seconds` for node. For Nginx, `proxy_connect_timeout`

Comment: where do i add that ?? cause im seeing that everywhere.

Comment: What are the values?

Comment: proxy_connect_timeout was set to 5s;

Comment: as for the req.connection.setTimeout(100000) i have no idea where i set or find that line.

Comment: You don't have to set that. It was just an example to show how to set timeout in Node. As for the `proxy_connect_timeout`, try increasing the value to 300

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234565/discussion-between-mr-gomer-and-psygik).

Comment: I tried it and it wont work. The server works perfectly if i go to my .env file in my react project and remove HTTPS=true.